# Silverlight Toolkit Themes: Exception on Setting Theme with TreeView

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I've run into a problem trying to programmatically apply a Silverlight Toolkit Theme. An exception is raised upon setting the theme, under certain conditions.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="Press To Set Theme"
            Click="Button_Click" />
    <sdk:TreeView>
        <sdk:TreeViewItem Header="Items">
            <TextBlock Text="Item" />
        </sdk:TreeViewItem>
    </sdk:TreeView>
</StackPanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TwilightBlueTheme.SetIsApplicationTheme(Application.Current, true);
}
```

If I start it, then expand the TreeView, and then click the button, I get this:

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
    at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
```

EDIT:

I've now tried a different way of doing this, and it still breaks with the same error. I wrapped the xaml in a Theme, like so:

```
<toolkit:Theme x:Name="ThemeContainer"
               ThemeUri="/System.Windows.Controls.Theming.TwilightBlue;component/Theme.xaml">
...
</toolkit:Theme>
```

And then changed the theme-switching to:

```
Theme themeContainer = (Theme)((FrameworkElement)Application.Current.RootVisual).FindName("ThemeContainer");

themeContainer.ThemeUri = new Uri("/System.Windows.Controls.Theming.ExpressionDark;component/Theme.xaml"), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Same situation: it works, except if I've already expanded the TreeView then it breaks with the same error.

SL4 w/ April 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's seems that this is a bug from SL toolkit. I get this error if set the theme when the tree is expanded:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Failed to assign to
>   property 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.Content'.

Anyway, the usual way of using themes works flawless:

```
<theme:TwilightBlueTheme>
    ...
</theme:TwilightBlueTheme>
```

This is the theme namespace definition:

```
xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Theming;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Theming.TwilightBlue"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2010/05/31/dynamically-apply-and-change-theme-with-the-silverlight-toolkit.aspx) about how dynamically change the theme with Silverlight Toolkit

Comment: Hmm. That seem very messy. The release notes for the April 2010 Toolkit seemed to imply that the IsApplicationTheme was a/the way to go for theming the whole app... and, more importantly, why on earth does it work _except_ under certain conditions.